# Eclipse unhandled event loop while trying to run app

Tags: android, eclipse, loops

I'm having this weird problem. I was trying to add ads to my app, and I followed the tutorial at this site.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eclipse#include_the_google_play_services_library

In the tutorial it tells you to import the google-play-services-lib to eclipse, and add it to your project. I did that, and everything else, but  when I went to run the app it got stuck in a loop. It just keeps saying launching new configuration, and then after a while it gives me an error. How do I fix this? Everything was working fine, until I did this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not to sure what I did. I gave eclipse more memory to use, but It still gave me the error. Then out of nowhere it started working again.
If you want to try adding more memory, put this this in the eclipse.ini file...

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

-Xms512m

-Xmx1024m

I'm using a linux system, and my file was in /opt/eclipse, but yours might be in /usr/eclipse. It all depends on where you put it.